# Experimental Survey on Different Heuristics for Knapsack Problem

Tags: reference-request, np-complete, optimization, heuristics

I am looking for a good survey/study of experimental results of heuristics for Knapsack problem (or implemented libraries in java/c++). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you interested in some particular variants or constraints? [Wilbaut, C., Hanafi, S., & Salhi, S. (2008). A survey of effective heuristics and their application to a variety of knapsack problems. IMA Journal of Management Mathematics, 19(3), 227-244](http://pdf.aminer.org/000/226/090/the_quadratic_multiple_knapsack_problem_and_three_heuristic_approaches_to.pdf) might be interesting to you.

Comment: Do you mean heuristics literally, or are you really after approximation algorithms and the like?

Comment: @Raphael: real practical good heuristics.